# Input необычная форма

Tags: html, css, css3

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добрый день. Подскажите как на input сделать такие углы ? на кнопке через before и after , а вот адекватно input не знаю как сделать. Просто как фон сделать тоже не хочется.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Суть решения в применении `skewX` для обрамляющего элемента и обратного`skewX` для `input`.

В этом примере `border` у `div` вокруг, а если наклонять только `input` то текст в них тоже будет наклонен.

```css
.input {
    width: 250px;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    margin: 0 0 5px 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.input input {
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 6px 0 8px 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.input.left,
.input.right input {
   transform: skewX(25deg);
}

.input.right,
.input.left input {
    transform: skewX(-25deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="input left">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Ваше имя" />
</div>
<div class="input right">
    <input type="text" placeholder="7-(___)-___-____" />
</div>
```

Comment: Только вместо div лучше использовать label.

Comment: @Qwertiy, это ж, вроде, невалидно?

Comment: @CbIPoK2513, с чего бы? Вот div класть в label невалидно, а input - самое то - так почти всегда делается.

Comment: @Qwertiy, значить я где-то что-то упустил))